# Is there a way to merge two sets of pictures into one?

Tags: haskell, gloss

I am trying to display a grid of lines with a set of cells that fill the squares in said lines.

I have already tried concatenating them like simple lists.

This is the grid of lines. It is displayed correctly on its own.

```hs
grid = translate (fromIntegral width * (-0.5)) 
                 (fromIntegral height * (-0.5)) 
                 (pictures (concat [
                                    [line [(i * unitWidth, 0.0)
                                          ,(i * unitWidth, fromIntegral height)]
                                    ,line [(0.0, i * unitHeight)
                                          ,(fromIntegral width, i * unitHeight)]
                                    ]
                                   | i <- [1..gridDimension]]
                            )
                 )
```

This is the set of units that are drawn between the lines, also displayed correctly on its own.

```hs
units = pictures [translate ((x*unitWidth - unitWidth/2) + (fromIntegral width*(-0.5))) 
                            ((y*unitHeight - unitHeight/2) + (fromIntegral height*(-0.5)))
                            unit
                 | x <- [1..gridDimension], y <- [1..gridDimension]]
```

My main method:

```hs
main = display window backgroundColor units
```

I can exchange units for grid in this place and it works fine.
I also tried this:

```hs
main = display window backgroundColor (units++grid)
```

It threw the following error:

```
40: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[a0]’ with actual type ‘Picture’
    • In the first argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘grid’
      In the third argument of ‘display’, namely ‘(grid ++ units)’
      In the expression: display window backgroundColor (grid ++ units)
   |
10 | main = display window backgroundColor (grid++units)
   |                                        ^^^^

/home/georg/Desktop/THM/6_semester/funktionale_programmierung/my/app/Main.hs:10:40: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Picture’ with actual type ‘[a0]’
    • In the third argument of ‘display’, namely ‘(grid ++ units)’
      In the expression: display window backgroundColor (grid ++ units)
      In an equation for ‘main’:
          main = display window backgroundColor (grid ++ units)
   |
10 | main = display window backgroundColor (grid++units)
   |                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^

/home/georg/Desktop/THM/6_semester/funktionale_programmierung/my/app/Main.hs:10:46: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[a0]’ with actual type ‘Picture’
    • In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘units’
      In the third argument of ‘display’, namely ‘(grid ++ units)’
      In the expression: display window backgroundColor (grid ++ units)
   |
10 | main = display window backgroundColor (grid++units)
   |                                              ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**`(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-43--43-) function appends two lists, a `Picture` is not a list, so you can not use that function.

You can however use the [**`(<>) :: Semigroup m => m -> m -> m`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-60--62-) here, since a `Picture` is an instance of a `Semigroup`:

we thus can write it like:

```
main = display window backgroundColor (units <> grid)
```

or you can use [**`pictures :: [Picture] -> Picture`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss-1.13.0.1/docs/Graphics-Gloss-Data-Picture.html#v:pictures) again, and include your `units` and `grid`, like:

```
main = display window backgroundColor (pictures [units, grid])
```

Comment: grid as well as units is not a picture, it is already built with the "pictures" function, so it should be of the type [Picture].
However (units <>grid) worked. No idea what that is but thank you very much.
edit: Both your solutions work btw. How I did not just try and error this is beyond me.

Comment: @gimbar: but `pictures` has type `[Picture] -> Picture` [ref](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss-1.13.0.1/docs/Graphics-Gloss-Data-Picture.html#v:pictures), so you collapsed it to a `Picture`, note that the compiler also derived that type.

Comment: @Wiilem Van Onsem
You are right, too. How I missed these obvious things is troubling. I pondered over this for a whole weekend.

Comment: Missing these things may have something to do with insisting you can run before you learn to walk. Have you considered studying the fundamentals of the language?